# iPhone Location Services - how to recognize which sources (WLAN, GPS) have been used

Tags: iphone, service, gps, location

Is it possible to find out what sources the location services used to calculate my position. I would like to have this information so that I can show the user if we used GPS, GPRS or WLAN to detect his position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No apple doesn't provide a way to know from which source the device has calculated the points but if you want to check whether points are from (Cell Tower/WiFi) or GPS then you should check the vertical accuracy of the CLLocation object which is negative if points are not from GPS.
Hope in future apple will provide this facility also. If someone has more good idea, he/she is welcomed.